# NullReference durning testing controller with NUnit and Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I obtain a NullReference exception in my test. When I comment  ***eventsRepository.AddEvent(eve, User.Identity.GetUserId());*** in controller than it goes through.

How Can I fix it ?

**Controller's Method**

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult CreateEvent(Event eve)
{
    if (eve.DateOfBegining < DateTime.Now)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("DateOfBegining", "");
    }

    if (eve.MaxQuantityOfPlayers < eve.MinCount)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("MinCount", "");
    }

    if (eve.ConflictSides.Count < 2 || eve.ConflictSides.Count > 10)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ConflictSides", "");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("CreateEvent", eve);
    }
    else
    {
        eventsRepository.AddEvent(eve, User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return RedirectToAction("EventsList");
    }
}
```

**AddEvent**

```
void AddEvent(Event ev, string userId);
```

**Test's method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateEvent_AddEvent_returns_EventsList()
{
    // arrange
    var EventRepo = new Mock<IEventRepository>();
    var ParticipantsRepo = new Mock<IParticipants>();

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2200, 1, 23);
    Event eve = new Event() 
    {
        ConflictSides = new List<ConflictSide>() { 
                                                new ConflictSide{ Name ="niebiescy"},
                                                new ConflictSide{ Name ="czerwoni"},
                                                new ConflictSide{ Name ="fioletowi"},
                                                },
        DateOfBegining = dt,
        Description = "bardzo dlugi opid na potrzeby testu",
        EventCreator= "userId",
        EventName = "najlepsza",
        FpsLimitInBuildings=300,
        FpsLimitOnOpenField=500,
        Hicap = new MagazineTyp(){ifAllow = true, ifOnlySemi = false},
        MidCap = new MagazineTyp(){ifAllow = true, ifOnlySemi = false},
        LowCap = new MagazineTyp(){ifAllow = true, ifOnlySemi = false},
        RealCap = new MagazineTyp(){ifAllow = true, ifOnlySemi = false},
        MaxQuantityOfPlayers = 50,
        MinCount = 10           
    };

    var target = new EventController(EventRepo.Object, ParticipantsRepo.Object);

    // act

    RedirectToRouteResult result = target.CreateEvent(eve) as RedirectToRouteResult;

    // assert

    // EventRepo.Verify(a => a.AddEvent(It.IsAny<Event>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());

    Assert.AreEqual("EventsList", result.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```

Comment: You are accessing `User.Identity.GetUserId()` but the User property of the controller was not setup in your test method.

Comment: Heres another way to mock it with fakeiteasy http://stackoverflow.com/a/39898952/2672291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `User.Identity.GetUserId()` but the `User` property of the controller was not setup in your test method hence it will be null when accessed

you will need to set the controller context with a dummy user account. Here is a helper class you can use to mock the `HttpContext` needed to get the user principal.

```cs
private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
    private readonly IPrincipal user;

    public MockHttpContext(string username, string[] roles = null) {
        var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles ?? new string[] { });
        user = principal;
    }

    public override IPrincipal User {
        get {
            return user;
        }
        set {
            base.User = value;
        }
    }
}
```

in your test after initializing the target controller you would need to set the controller context

```cs
//...other coder

var target = new EventController(EventRepo.Object, ParticipantsRepo.Object);
target.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext {
    Controller = target,
    HttpContext = new MockHttpContext("fakeuser@example.com")
};

//...other coder
```