# Null reference on user identity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I am new to writing a unit test case. I am getting error on `User.Identity`. I saw mocking is the resolution for that and I tried which is not working in my case. I have added my code

My Controller

```
public ActionResult CreateStage ( EnthiranStageViewModel enthiranStage )
{
    if ( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        Stage stage = enthiran.Insert_Stage(enthiranStage);
        //logging Stage Creation
        util.ApplicationLog(new ViewModel.Logs.ApplicationLogViewModel
        {
         GameCategorys = GameCategory.Enthiran,
         Event = Events.EnthiranStageCreation,
         SessionAttemptId = null,
         UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>( ),
         OptionalParameter1 = enthiranStage.GameId,
         OptionalParameter2 = stage.Id,
         Description = "Enthiran stage created"
        });
        return RedirectToAction("Stages", new
        {
            id = stage.GameId
        });
    }
    return View( );
}
```

and below is my test case

```
[TestMethod( )]
public void createStage ( )
{
    EnthiranStageViewModel enthiranStage = new EnthiranStageViewModel
    {
        StageType=0,
        TriggerBeginType = Akton.Areas.Challenge.Models.TriggerType.Manual,
        TriggerEndType= Akton.Areas.Challenge.Models.TriggerType.Manual,
        TimeLimit = new TimeSpan(9, 6, 13),
        TriggerBeginTime= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        TriggerEndTime= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        StartValueType= Akton.Areas.Challenge.Models.StartValueType.Global,
        StageDate= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        Proforma=25,
        GameId=19,
        CreatedTime=new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        UpdatedTime= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        StageName="Test",

    };
    EnthiranController controller = new EnthiranController( );
    JsonResult actual = controller.CreateStage(enthiranStage) as JsonResult;
    var result = actual.Data;
    Assert.AreEqual("{ success = True }", result.ToString( ));
}
```

Here I have to pass the `userId` in the `ViewModel.Logs.ApplicationLogViewModel`, I have no idea how to do that.

How do I get the `userId` which is passing through `applicationLogViewModel`?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230776/how-to-mock-httpcontext-user/40234602#40234602

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39453132/5233410

Comment: You should also take note that the method under test can return either a view result or redirect to action result but the unit test is checking for a JSON result. which will cause `actual` variable to be `null`

Comment: The main reason for the null user is because the method is accessing `User.Identity` but the `User` property of the controller was not setup/arranged in the test method.

Comment: @Nkosi Hello, thanks for the comment, i need to know instead of Json result, if i pass action result, how should i write Assert? for example in my controller i am passing the value then redirecting the page. please see above my controller

Comment: ActionResult actual = controller.CreateStage(enthiranStage) as ActionResult; how should i write unit test case for my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to change `EnthiranController` and pass, for example, `IUserContext`, something like this:

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    public IPrincipal User {get;}
}
```

then pass that through constructor to the controller, and use that context to retrieve the user.

```
ctor EnthiranController(IUserContext userContext)
```

Then slightly change unit test to mock all these interfaces. Also instead of `JsonResult` you can use `ActionResult` or `RedirectToRouteResult` as it is shown in following example.

```
[TestMethod( )]
public void createStage ( )
{
    //arrange
    EnthiranStageViewModel enthiranStage = new EnthiranStageViewModel
    {
        StageType=0,
        TriggerBeginType = Akton.Areas.Challenge.Models.TriggerType.Manual,
        TriggerEndType= Akton.Areas.Challenge.Models.TriggerType.Manual,
        TimeLimit = new TimeSpan(9, 6, 13),
        TriggerBeginTime= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        TriggerEndTime= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        StartValueType= Akton.Areas.Challenge.Models.StartValueType.Global,
        StageDate= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        Proforma=25,
        GameId=19,
        CreatedTime=new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        UpdatedTime= new DateTime(2016, 09, 3, 9, 6, 13),
        StageName="Test"    
    };

    Mock<IPrincipal> mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    //TODO: setup mockPrincipal
    Mock<IUserContext> mockUserContext = new Mock<IUserContext>();
    mockUserContext.Setup(p => p.User).Returns(mockPrincipal.Object);

    EnthiranController controller = new EnthiranController(mockUserContext.Object);

    //act
    var actual = controller.CreateStage(enthiranStage) as RedirectToRouteResult; 

    //assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment, its working fine, but i need to know instead of Json result, if i pass action result, how should i write Assert? for example in my controller i am passing the value then redirecting the page.

Comment: @Sriram if you want to verify that redirect branch is executed then you can verify that `ActionResult` is of type `RedirectToRouteResult `.

Comment: once i change the Json result to action result, variable actual getting null reference error. and also i need to redirect that to another page as per controller data.

Comment: @Sriram look at the post from Nkosi. That is the way also how you can verify, I will edit my answer to include that peace of code.

Comment: @Lepijohnny as you have it updated in your answer I can remove mine. Just make sure to also mention it as one of the changes needed to solve original problem.